# Undefined reference to libusb_hotplug_register_callback

Tags: c, linux, libusb, usb-drive

I am writing a [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) program. It works fine, I can do bulk transfers, control transfers, etc. Now, I wanted to add the hotplug support. As per libusb 1.0 documentation, hot plug support is not available on Windows. So, the following snippet returns false as expected.

```
if(libusb_has_capability (LIBUSB_CAP_HAS_HOTPLUG))
{
    hasHotPlugSupport = true;
    status = libusb_hotplug_register_callback (context, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE , VENDOR_ID,
                                             PRODUCT_ID, CLASS_ID, hotplugAttachCallback, this, &hotplugHandle[0]);
    if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        hasHotPlugSupport = false;
    }

    status = libusb_hotplug_register_callback (context, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE , VENDOR_ID,
                                               PRODUCT_ID, CLASS_ID, hotplugDetachCallback, this, &hotplugHandle[1]);
    if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        hasHotPlugSupport = false;
    }
    future = QtConcurrent::run (this,&LibUsbDevice::eventThread);
}
```

So, I wanted to test hotplug support on Linux, but the program doesn't compile until I comment out the hotplug functions. I get following error:

> error: undefined reference to `libusb_hotplug_register_callback'

Comment: The doxygen documentation says this function is available since 1.0.16. Are you sure your lib is in sync with the header files you are using?

Comment: @Alexander yes the issue is I am using 1.0.16 on Windows and 1.0.12 on Linux.

Comment: so what is your question then? You are using a function which does not exist in the library version you are using. Upgrade it to >1.0.16

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linker issue to me.

This is because the "register_callback" function is present in the header file, but it does not exist in the libraries that are referred...

Comment: yes, but surprisingly, only the register_callback function is missing rest all are their.